# Restructuring the sql

Tags: sql

I try to implement a table which will be used as a apply operation. Customers apply for a loan and employees will approve them. The corresponding sql is:

```
create table approve(
   employee_ID char(8),
   customer_ID char(8), 
   loanID char(8) primary key,
   foreign key(employee_ID) references employee(ID),
   foreign key(customer_ID) references customer(ID) 
)
```

However the problem is when I try to insert an element it asks me to enter the loanID. However loan id's should be displayed and employee should determine based on this loanID. Isn't it logical? If it's logical how I can modify the code?

Comment: Where does loanID come from? Isn't is coming from another table?

Comment: Yes it comes from loan table

Comment: You defined loadID as primary key of the table. A primary key column is not optional when you insert a new row. Maybe you should explain you problem a bit better. If it is a foreign key column, then it is not a primary key... you'll need to define another primary key, if any.

Comment: So one loan (a record in load table) can be used multiple times, for instance granted by employee E1 to customer C1 and by employee E2 to customer C2?

Comment: Actually I don't like to encounter this kind of problems. How can I solve it? If I make all three attributes which are employee id, customer id and loanID, will the problem be solved?

Comment: Which problems? Is this an answer to my question? All I asked was, wether a loan can be used multiple times or just once.

Comment: I dont understand, why you need this table if you already have Customer, Employee and Loan tables? Just add customer and employee foreign keys to Loan table and bit flag for approval?

Comment: Actually assistant requires the approve table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `loanID` comes from another table, you should also address it as foreign key, just like you do with `employee` and `customer`:

```
create table approve(
   employee_ID char(8),
   customer_ID char(8), 
   loan_ID char(8),
   foreign key(loan_ID) references loan(ID),
   foreign key(employee_ID) references employee(ID),
   foreign key(customer_ID) references customer(ID) 
)
```

If you want to prevent the same loan to have multiple entries in the table `approve`, create an index:

```
create unique index approve_loan_ID on approve (loan_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one-to-one relationship then the structure is fine.

Loan and approve can share primary key

Creating an approvement post requires a loan post. And a loan can only be approved once?

All you need to do is setting the primary key of approve to be a foreign key of loan.

```
foreign key(loan_ID) references loan(ID)
```

Comment: Yes it is one to one relationship. But will it ensure that one loan will be belong to the one customer and one employee?

Comment: As the primary key needs to be unique, there can only be one approve per loan. So it will guarantee it. If there needs to be more, employee and possibly customer needs to be part of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table strucure so that you have only Loan, Customer and Employee tables.

Add relations as such

Loan 1 - * Customer

"Customer can have multiple loans"

Loan 0..1 - * Employee

"Loan can only have 1 approval from employee"

Add Approved bit flag for Loan to mark it as approved, or enum to mark is as "applied" / "approved" / "rejected" / "whatever".

Answer (score 0):

If a loan can be used just once, there is no reason for a new table.

```
alter table loan add granter_employee_ID char(8);

alter table loan add grantee_customer_ID char(8);

alter table loan add constraint fk_granter_employee_id 
  foreign key (granter_employee_id) references employee(id);

alter table loan add constraint fk_grantee_customer_id
  foreign key (grantee_customer_id) references customer(id);
```

I suppose even that a loan gets entered when a customer applies for it? Then you would make the customer not nullable.

```
alter table loan add grantee_customer_id char(8) not null;
```

(And well, you could name the column differently then, as the loan wouldn't be granted already when entered.)